# datetime on a single row and not a column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rows

I have a df where a single date has underlying values in the column. The row with the date has some names in it as well.

I would like to convert the dates in the single row to datetime(currently stored as strings).

One solution-though not a fan of it is-index by other columns(strings) then transpose table convert the dates (now in columns) to datetime and then transpose once again.
Sample data-

The dates are stored as strings,I would like them is datetime.

Was wondering if there is a better way.

```
    C   N   D   12-10 12-11  12-12
1   NW  NW  NW   19    12     16     
2   NW  NW  NW   11    14     18     
3   NW  NW  NW   45    46     93
```

Comment: How do you expect your output dataframe to look like? I confess I didn't understand what  you are trying to do

Comment: Just trying to fix the formatting of dtypes

Comment: @AmeyaVikram I'm confused about your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'C':['NW','NW','NW'],'N':['NW','NW','NW'],'D':['NW','NW','NW'],'12-10':[19,11,45],'12-11':[12,14,46],'12-12':[16,18,93]})

cols_to_datetime = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x+'-2020','%m-%d-%Y') for x in df.columns[3:]]

df.columns = df.columns[0:3].to_list() + cols_to_datetime
```

Comment: Is there a better way than doing so for each column df is actually quite big and hence the above is longer than the transpose method(or is it possible to define a function/loop that can do this)

Comment: yes just iterate over each relevant column in a for loop. if you like the answer please upvot/accept

Comment: Could you write the loop out-I don't know how you write the loop for the string values in under the dates.

Also those string numbers need to be converted to a float64/32

Comment: I added the for loop. can you explain what you mean by string numbers convert to float? You mean they are number type and need to be converted to string?

Comment: The numbers below the date are strings and need to be converted to numbers. To add some clarity to the question the df is being written to a csv so the column headers with dates need to be in date time format

Comment: ok, I updated, maybe now it is what you want?